# Can't Access Sqlite db with Postman Even with No Auth Schedule Set Up

Tags: node.js, vue.js, sqlite, express

I have Postman trying to hit my API for a vue app that uses express on the backend. I have the express server set up to use sqlite3 and the server seems to run but I only get errors when trying to access its methods via api calls.

First, I created the vue app with the basic command `vue create .` and I added several extra options such as vuex, router, sass, etc... Then I made a folder called `backend` with 2 files `index.js` and `config.js`. Here are the files:

index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const { db, port } = require("./config.js");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);
app.use(cors());

const getUsers = (request, response) => {
  console.log("ran /test");
  db.query("SELECT * FROM wallets", (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }
    response.status(200).json(results.rows);
  });
};

const registerUser = (request, response) => {
  const { wallet } = request.body;
  insertNewUser(wallet)
    .then((results) => {
      if (results) {
        console.log("it worked");
      }

      response
        .status(201)
        .json({ status: "success", message: "Wallet added." });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      response.status(500).json({ status: "fail", message: error });
    });
};

function insertNewUser(wallet) {
  return db.query("INSERT INTO wallets (wallet) VALUES ($1)", [wallet]);
}

app.route("/test", getUsers);
app.route("/register", registerUser);

app.listen(port);
console.log("App is running on port " + port);
```

config.js

```
const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3");
const path = require("path");

let db = new sqlite3.Database(
  path.resolve(__dirname, "test.db"),
  sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE,
  (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
    console.log("Connected to the database.");
  }
);

module.exports = {
  db,
  port: "30005",
};
```

I created a sqlite db in the `backend` directory with db sqlite browser as displayed in this image:
[image]

This is what I get when I do a postman get request to the `test` function which is supposed to display wallet entries in the database
[image]

Btw I am running this server with `yarn run start:server` which is a script in my `package.json` file in the root project directory. This is what the `scripts` section of my `package.json` looks like:

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "start:server": "nodemon backend/index.js --ignore 'src/**/*.js'"
  },
```

So why are my get requests failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was 2 things causing this problem. First, instead of `query` I used `get`. Second instead of `app.route` I used `app.get`. The code that correctly runs the `/test` api looks like this:

index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const { db, port } = require("./config.js");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);
app.use(cors());

const getUsers = (request, response) => {
  console.log("ran /test");
  db.get("SELECT * FROM wallets", (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }
    response.status(200).json(results.rows);
  });
};

app.get("/test", getUsers);

app.listen(port);
console.log("App is running on port " + port);
```